# How can I get the SSDT Extended Property values of a table object via DacFx

Tags: t4, sql-server-data-tools, dac

i'd like to retrieve the value of the extended property of my SSDT tables and columns so i can use it for some model generation stuff i'm working on using T4.

I can't find any examples of this done online, has anyone else done this?

These are the extended properties you can add with the following:

```
GO
EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description', @value = 
N'somepropertytext', @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = N'dbo', 
@level1type = N'TABLE', @level1name = N'table_name', @level2type = 
N'COLUMN', @level2name = N'column_name';
```

in my T4 template where i'm loading the column info I have this:

```
var property = column.GetProperty<string>(???);
```

I'm not sure what goes in the ??? part to get this extended property information. Any ideas?

I am able to get other properties about the column like nullable, precision, etc.

MS doc on this is a bit... lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extended property isn't a property of the column, it's the other way around, i.e. the column is what the extended property refers to!

```
var propertyName = column.GetReferencing()
    .Where(x=> x.ObjectType.Name == "ExtendedProperty").First()
    .Name.ToString();

var propertyValue = column.GetReferencing()
    .Where(x=> x.ObjectType.Name == "ExtendedProperty").First()
    .GetProperty(ExtendedProperty.Value);
```

Extending this method-chaining mayhem to loop over *all* extended properties of the object is left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: This. Is. Awesome. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just as a follow up for anyone reading this, I have the following:
`foreach (var table in allTables)
        { 
             var tableextended = table.GetReferencing()
                .Where(x => x.ObjectType.Name == "ExtendedProperty")
                .FirstOrDefault()?
                .GetProperty(ExtendedProperty.Value);

             if(tableextended) 
                 //do some stuff here
         }
`
and confirmed it was working and pulling the property fields correctly.